# CRUD operations validation

Tags: asp.net-web-api, domain-driven-design, crud, webapi, user-roles

Supposed I have a database with 3 tables:

1. Customers
2. Orders
3. CustomerOrders

I build a WebAPI with standard auth using bearer token and I have a middleware to receive all necessary claims from the token, and I have a controller for basic CRUD operations for Orders.

for example:
DELETE - Orders/{id}
PUT - Orders/{id}

How can I make sure that the order that the user is trying to manipulate belongs to the current user?
Do I first need to query the database to make sure that the OrderId belongs to the current UserId before each operation? or is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: The problem is that you cannot trust the client. even if the UI will display the user's orders, nothing prevents the client from manipulating the request to the backend with any order ID.

Answer (score 1):

You can somehow manage to have the information if the user the token was issued for granted the client application to manipulate orders in general dependending on the options of your identity management and token provider.

But to make sure that ***this specific order belongs to the current user*** can only be checked in your backend and this needs of course to be done with every operation. The order id could be brute-forced (**guessed**) and **manipulated** in the request so therefore you need check this on each request.

I suggest though to extract this checking logic - does the passed order id belong to the user id provided in the token - to some service method to make it reusable from different places. In your case, for instance reuse it for the different CRUD methods such as DELETE and PUT.